# JQuery clone <select> element

Tags: jquery, html, forms, select, clone

I want to clone a <select> input in HTML using JQuery.
I'm not sure how to go about it, so thought I'd ask here.

Particularly interested in the best way to write it back into the document as well.

My select element looks like this:

```
<select id="options">
    <option value="1">Opt 1</option>
    <option value="2">Opt 2</option>
    <option value="3">Opt 3</option>
</select>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Attention: the selected attribute will not be copied over because of a bug in jQuery. The selectedIndex is lost after clone. You'll have to manually set the selected value again. http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9997 It looks like jQuery might not fix this soon. Good luck!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

See: http://api.jquery.com/clone/

```
$('select#options').clone().attr('id', 'newOptions').appendTo('.blah');
```

appendTo(...) is only one way to insert the cloned elements. Other methods can be found here: http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/

Comment: Thanks, I've broken your answer over two lines because I prefer it that way.

Comment: Note from the docs on jquery clone, it won't clone anything that was selected: "For performance reasons, the dynamic state of certain form elements (e.g., user data typed into textarea and user selections made to a select) is not copied to the cloned elements. When cloning input elements, the dynamic state of the element (e.g., user data typed into text inputs and user selections made to a checkbox) is retained in the cloned elements."  see http://api.jquery.com/clone/

Answer (score 11):

How about this?

```
<select id="options">
    <option value="1">Opt 1</option>
    <option value="2">Opt 2</option>
    <option value="3">Opt 3</option>
</select>
```

//target

```
<select id="options2">
</select>

$('#options').find('option').clone().appendTo('#options2');
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

Only problem with the accepted answer is that if your select contains optgroups they will not be copied over. In that case, the easiest way I found was to just do this:

```
$('#options2').html($('#options').html());
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has a [clone](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) method built-in. There are many [options](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/) for how to add the cloned element back in. The proper choice is dependent on your application.

Answer (score 0):

you can attr option selected true with select change, then use clone is ok.

```js
$("#options").off("change").on("change", function() {
    var val = $(this).val();

    $(this).find("option[value=" + val + "]").attr("selected", true);
});
```

```js
$("#options").off("change").on("change", function() {
    var val = $(this).val();

    $(this).find("option[value=" + val + "]").attr("selected", true);
});
```