# Dynamic form boxes

Tags: javascript, php, html

Stuck on a tough situation!

I have a form for inputting different cities where user want to go.

I have a form box and a submit button.

Now I want my user to enter as many cities he likes, in order to do so he must click on a link `Add 1 more city` and one more form box should appear.

How can I perform such task in HTML

Comment: There are many examples of dynamically adding elements to the web page using Javascript. Please do some research and make an attempt to solve it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jquery [`clone`](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) function.

```
$('select#options').clone().attr('id', 'newOptions').appendTo('.blah');
```

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906644/jquery-clone-select-element)

**UPDATE**

found good [snippet](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/dynamic-form-fields-add-amp-remove) for you. exactly what you need

Answer (score 1):

This is a nice way to do it:

```
<div id="inputBoxes"> 
    <input />
</div>

<button type="button">Add more</button>

$('button').click(function() {
    $('#inputBoxes').append('<input>');
});
```

Hope it will help,

Zorken17

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $('#inputBoxes').append('<input>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>


<div id="inputBoxes"> 
    <input />
</div>

<button type="button">Add more</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

put city box in a div and assign a id to that div and call a menthod of java script on the click of add 1 button then in method append other city box html in div through java script.

Answer (score 0):

maybe thats a good starting point

```
<form id="myForm">
<div id="cities">
    <input class="city" type="text" />
</div>
```

```
var $cityInputs;

function registerEvents() {
    $cityInputs = $('input.city').not(':disabled');

    $cityInputs.blur(function(event){
        var $element = $(event.target);

        if ($element.val().trim().length !== 0)         {
            appendNewInput.call($('#cities'));
            $element.attr('disabled','disabled');
        }
    })
}

function appendNewInput() {
    this.append('<input class="city" type="text">');

    registerEvents();
}

registerEvents();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9ckv5f23/3/