# Select input data attribute not passing in jQuery appendTo form input

Tags: jquery

If the form is selected in the initial state, the data is passed. But the cloning form doesn't pass data from the select to the next form. If I duplicate the form at the beginning it also passes the data. But I want the cloned form to pass the data.

```js
$('input#clone').click(function() {
  $("div#old").clone().attr('id', 'new_form').appendTo("body")
})

$(".product").change(function() {
  newPrice = $(this).children(':selected').data('price');
  $(this).parent().next('.pricebox').find('.price').val(newPrice);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="button" value="Clone" id="clone" />
<hr>
<div id="old">
  <div class="">
    <select class="product" name="product[]">
      <option value="1" data-price="1.99">1</option>
      <option value="2" data-price="2.99">2</option>
      <option value="3" data-price="3.99">3</option>
      <option value="4" data-price="4.99">4</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="pricebox">
    <input type="text" name="price[]" class="price" value="00" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is no `textarea` element in your example. Not sure what you are trying to Clone.

Comment: Select data-price not passing price on to input field except first one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JQuery clone <select> element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906644/jquery-clone-select-element). See specifically [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906644/jquery-clone-select-element#comment40060226_3906644) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906644/jquery-clone-select-element#comment36978115_3906668).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  $('input#clone').click(function(e) {);
    var newForm = $("div#old").clone();
    newForm.attr('id', 'new_form_' + ($("[id^='new_form']").length + 1)).appendTo(".forms");
    $("select", newForm).val($("#old select").val());
  });

  $(".forms").on("change", ".product", function(e) {
    newPrice = $("option:selected", this).data('price');
    $(this).parent().next('.pricebox').find('.price').val(newPrice);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="button" value="Clone" id="clone" />
<hr>
<div class="forms">
  <div id="old">
    <div class="">
      <select class="product" name="product[]">
        <option value="1" data-price="1.99">1</option>
        <option value="2" data-price="2.99">2</option>
        <option value="3" data-price="3.99">3</option>
        <option value="4" data-price="4.99">4</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="pricebox">
      <input type="text" name="price[]" class="price" value="1.99" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This properly clones the item and resets the Value.It also uses proper delegation to ensure all new dynamic elements get the same callback. This also ensures that all items have unique IDs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/) to get change on created element then use [each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/) to do a loop on all element.

NOTE: ID must be unique, you need to change it to class if you want more than one element.

```js
$('input#clone').click(function() {
  $("div.old").clone().attr('id', 'new_form').appendTo("body")
})

$(document).on('change', '.product', function(event) {
  newPrice = $(this).children(':selected').data('price');
  $(this).parent().next('.pricebox').find('.price').val(newPrice);
  $('.product').each(function() {
    //console.log($(this).val());
    console.log($(this).parent('div:first').nextAll('.pricebox').find('.price').val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="button" value="Clone" id="clone" />
<hr>
<div class="old">
  <div class="">
    <select class="product" name="product[]">
      <option value="1" data-price="1.99">1</option>
      <option value="2" data-price="2.99">2</option>
      <option value="3" data-price="3.99">3</option>
      <option value="4" data-price="4.99">4</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="pricebox">
    <input type="text" name="price[]" class="price" value="00" />
  </div>
</div>
```